# Knockout mapping and binding after null -> Object

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a viewmodel which has some `observables` and `observableArrays`.
Depending on the page you are looking at it will fill up a certain observable or observable array. and then map it.

However from time to time there might be a subproperty which has currently a null value in it which i can create a new instance of through an api call (default values and so on server sided handled, seperation of concerns in mind, no Business Logic client sided!).
So when i do the `$.get()` request i placed it directly in the object and the data shows up in my viewmodel, however it is not mapped to the fields where they are bound to?

Binding works, but only one way (read). What do i miss? The api call (example), which places everything in the vm:

```
$.get('../../../../../api/addresses/?id=new&subjectid=' + subjectid, null, vm.currentSubject()['CurrentAddressInfo'])
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code. The one line of code you've posted doesn't help at all.

Comment: I've changed the way the viewmodel is created server sided and i am now mapping to a secondary knockout vm if needed.
This fixed it for me...
also am i using ko.mapping now in order to have full sub property mapping where needed.

Sorry for the wait for feedback :)